# Particle attached in equilibrium to two elastic strings

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, elasticity, string

The question I'm trying to answer is this:[image]

This is the solution:

[image]

The only part of the solution I have a problem with is $x_{ps} + x_{qs}=l$, where $x_{ps}$ is the extension of the string from $P$ to $S$. I have found my own way to understand it but I highly doubt it's correct. Here's my understanding of it:

$$x_{ps}=l-PS$$
$$x_{qs}=l-QS$$
$$PS=3l-QS$$
$$QS=3l-PS$$
$$x_{ps} + x_{qs}=l-PS + (l-QS)=l-PS + (l - (3l-PS))= -l$$, where the negative sign becomes positive.

Comment: Use brace brackets for subscripts with more than one letter e.g. x_{ps} will give you $x_{ps}$ rather than $x_ps$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x_{ps}=PS-l$ and $x_{qs}=QS-l$ not the way you had it.  The stretched length of the strings is $l$, so if the stretched length is $PS$ then the extension has to be $PS-l$.